# Template Library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use a template library created by Phil Sturgeon. He has some great documentation for his template library but I've ran into a little bit of a problem with how I have my file structure done.

```
-views
    -layouts
        -default.php
    -partials
        -header_view.php
        -footer_view.php
        -metadata_view.php
    login_view.php
```

Inside of my login controller index function I have the following code to establish which layout to use and which view to load as the body of the template. I also have included what I have inside of the header_view.php file which I believe is what I'm not getting to work right. I was hoping to be able to target the metadata partial inside of the header_view. According to the documentation I'm doing it correctly, however, I'm getting an error undefined index metadata coming from the header_view.php file. Any light on this issue.

Documention from the github repostitory: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template

```
$this->template
        ->title('Login Form')
        ->set_partial('header', 'partials/header_view')
        ->set_partial('metadata', 'partials/metadata_view')
        ->set_partial('footer', 'partials/footer_view')
        ->set_layout('default')
        ->build('login_form_view');
```

default.php

```
<?php echo $template['partials']['header']; ?>

<?php echo $template['body']; ?>

<?php echo $template['partials']['footer']; ?>
```

header_view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $template['title']; ?></title>
    <?php echo $template['partials']['metadata']; ?>

</head>

    <body
```

Comment: You could try var_dumping the $template variable to see whats in there

Comment: It shows no partials being passed inside. I"m not sure why.

Comment: If I do the var_dump on the $template inside of the default.php layout it shows it but not if I do it inside of the header_view.php partial.

Comment: It looks like you can't nest things like that then, it seems like the library expects the partial to be within the default layout, not nested down within layout->header.

Comment: well; are you sure you want to use a template library ? codeigniter view loaded accepts 3rd parrameter can be adjusted to do just what this lib. is doing for you in much cleaner, easier and faster mehode; if you want i can show u an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well im a codeigniter fan; and i honestly think that the real power of CI that it doesnt come loaded with fancy "TEMPLATING lib" or auth lib; yet it give you all tools to build your own swiftly and very rappidly;

so my answer my not be what you really asking for but its a simple example of how you can build your own so called templaling lib in ci in less than 10mins and works flowlessly;

1. create MY_Controller inside applicaiton/core folder;

   ```
   class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

   protected $noEcho=true,$body = 'base/layout', $title = 'YOUR CONTROLLER TITLE',
   $js = array(), //filename
   $inline_js = '', //script
   $css = array(), 
   $inline_css = '', //style
   $content = array(); //html
   ```

inside it will be 3 basic functions

1. that set you page parts;
2. that manage your assets
3. that print out your end result page;

1

```
function output($data,$section='content'){

//checking type of data to be pushed its either array or string(html)
//this is a view it should be formated like this array( viewname,$data )
if( is_array($data) ){
  $this->content[ $section ][] = $this->load->view( $data[0], $data[1], TRUE );

  return $this;//to allow chaing

}elseif( is_string($data) ){//this is html

  $this->content[ $section ][] = $data;
  return $this;//to allow chaing
}

}
```

2nd is a function that let you add js,css and and inline js&css to this page;

```
function _asset( $link, $txt = FALSE ) {

if ( $txt !== FALSE ) {
  if ( $txt == 'js' )
    $this->inline_js[] = $txt;
  elseif ( $txt == 'css' )
    $this->inline_css[] = $txt;
}else{
  if ( pathinfo( $link, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) == 'css' ){
    $this->css[] = link_tag( base_url( 'assets/css/' . trim( $link, "/\\" ) ) );
  }else{
    $this->js[] = '<script src="' . base_url( 'assets/js/' . trim( $link, "/\\" ) ) . '"></script>';
  }   
}
return $this;
}
```

and at last a function that put all your parts together;

```
protected function print_page(){

  if ( $this->noEcho ) ob_clean();

  $data=array();

  $data[ 'title' ] = $this->title;
  $data[ 'css' ]        = is_array( $this->css ) ? implode( "\n", $this->css ) : '';
  $data[ 'js' ]         = is_array( $this->js ) ? implode( "\n", $this->js ) : '';
  $data[ 'inline_css' ] = ( $this->inline_css ) ? '<style>' . implode( "\n", $this->inline_css ) . '</style>' : '';
  $data[ 'inline_js' ]  = ( $this->inline_js ) ? implode( "\n", $this->inline_js ) : '';

  foreach ( $this->content as $section => $content ) {
    $data[ $section ] = is_array( $content ) ? implode( "\n\n\n ", $content ) : $content;
  } //$this->content as $section => $content

  return $this->load->view( $this->body, $data );

}
```

now put all three together and extend your controller to this base controller;

now for the example page your are trying to build i would do:

Controller :

```
public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->title = 'Controller title';
  $this->body = 'base/default';
  //load all your assets.. if its across all pages then load them in MY_controller construct
  $this->assets('jquery.min.js')
       ->assets('bootstrap.css')
       ->assets('alert("itworks");','js');//will be added to $inline_js
}

function index(){

$var = $This->some_model->get_data();

$this->output( array('some_View',$var) )
     ->output('<hr/>')
     ->output('THIS WILL BE IN $FOOTER','footer')
     ->print_page();

}
```

Now how clean is that :) ?;

now your controller will load view set on `this->body` and all pass all your sections to it.
so for above example your view will recieve 2 variables.

1. $content : ill contail some_view view +

   ---
2. $footer  : will contain html we passed it to it;
3. $css,$js,$inline_js,$inline_css variables contain all you assets
4. $title contain your page title;

at end
i hope that i hope this small demo help you understand the unlimited possibilities that these 3 small functions can do thanks to CI native view loader.

Comment: Great response. I'll award the bounty when I'm able to.